# Ada type declaration in C

Tags: c, ada

Is there a way to declare a new integer type in C?

In Ada,

```
type a is new integer;
```

means that a is not equivalent to say, an integer variable x.

I know that typedef can create an alias of an integer, but it is not the same as the above Ada code. It is more like a subtype in Ada.

Does anyone know?

Comment: No, you cannot create new types in C like this.  Typedefs are, as you've noted, merely aliases.  The only types you as a user can create are structures, unions, and enumerations, and those obviously aren't simple integer types.  You could do `struct myint { int i; };`, and that would create a user-defined type capable of storing one `int`, and having the same size as an `int`, but it wouldn't be too useful, as you couldn't, like, do arithmetic on it or anything.

Comment: Why do you want that?

Answer (score 1):

The type systems in C and Ada are different.

C uses a structural typing system for primitive types and a nominative typing system for structs and unions. C enums are simply named integer values, not a separate type from int. Since all int instances in C have the same structural representation on a given hardware platform, all typedefs of int are the same type.

Ada uses a nominative typing system for all types. Types are distinguished by their name and not by their structural layout. Thus type Integer is different than

```
type My_Int is new Integer;
```

My_Int is a type with a different name than Integer, even though it is derived from Integer. Therefore My_Int is not an Integer in Ada even though the two types share the same operations and the same memory layout.

A C typedef is similar to an Ada subtype inasmuch as a subtype is a member of its parent type. Subtypes and typedefs differ because a subtype of a scalar type may be defined with a restricted range such as:

```
subtype Natural is Integer range 0..Integer'Last;
subtype Positive is Integer range 1..Integer'Last;
```

Every instance of Natural or Positive is an Integer value. The subtypes have a restricted range of valid values compared to their base type.

There is no simple way a typedef statement in C can declare a restricted range of values. Proposals to that effect in the past have been rejected by the C standard committee.

Comment: If you wanted to confuse readers you could say `type Integer is new Standard.Integer;`.